# createCommand returns null in Yii model

Tags: php, yii

As title , I create a model in a PHP/Yii project,and create a method like below:

```
public function getRootId($id, $module) {
    $com = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('pid,id')
            ->from($this->tableName())
            ->where('id=:id', array(':id' => $id))
            ->andWhere('module=:module', array(':module' => $module))
            ->queryRow();
    if ($com['pid'] == 0 || empty($com['pid'])) {
        return $com['pid'];
    } else {
        $this->getRootId($com['pid'], $module);
    }
}
```

But I can't get the return value which can be dumped successfully before return.Then , I add a static tribute $_itmes

```
private static $_items;
```

and update the code like below:

```
public function getRootId($id, $module) {
    $com = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('pid,id')
            ->from($this->tableName())
            ->where('id=:id', array(':id' => $id))
            ->andWhere('module=:module', array(':module' => $module))
            ->queryRow();
    if ($com['pid'] == 0 || empty($com['pid'])) {
        self::$_times = $com['id'];
    } else {
        $this->getRootId($com['pid'], $module);
    }
}
```

Then use the self::$_items can get the target value.

Friends, who can tell me what happened?

Comment: In the first function, you're not returning anything from the else branch.

Comment: Just as you said,Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need return in the `else` case as well..

```
return $this->getRootId($com['pid'], $module);
```

The reason var_dump and static assignment are working is because it's recursive call, when it goes to if call it prints/assigns, but in case of return you need to return the value finally as well..

Comment: Thanks, you not only give me  details,but also the reason ,regards to you!Thank a million for your patience and hot.